# Expanding div's width to shrink anothers

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to make a div's width expand, when doing this I also want the div to the left of its width to shrink to a width 0px and disappear.

This is what I have [got to](https://codesandbox.io/embed/box-push-s6b6v)

I can't get the first(left) div's width to shrink. I also need the third div(right) to never change size, being unaffected by the animation.

*html*

```
 <div id='container'>
      <div id='one'>one</div>
      <div id='two'>two</div>
      <div id='three'>three</div>
 </div>
```

*css*

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  border-style: dotted;
  height: 100px;
  width: 318px;
}

#one {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: red;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

#two {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: cadetblue;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100px;
  animation: enter-right 20s linear infinite;
}
#three {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: goldenrod;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes enter-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  98%,
  100% {
    width: 100%;

  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for your boxes to have a position `absolute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used display: flex on the container and removed all positioning from elements.  I think it does what you're wanting:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  border-style: dotted;
  height: 100px;
  width: 318px;
}

#one {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 0px;
}

#two {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: cadetblue;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  animation: enter-right 20s linear infinite;
}

#three {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: goldenrod;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes enter-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  98%,
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    /* transform: translateX(100%); */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason to use an absolute position, you could try with an inline `Flexbox` container, using an animation over the `flex` shorthand property for the second element

```css
main {
  display: inline-flex; }

main div {
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px dashed #9bc;}

#one { 
  flex-basis: 200px; 
  width: 200px; }

#two { 
  flex: 1 0 0;
  animation: expand 5s linear 0s forwards; }

#three { 
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  width: 100px; }

@keyframes expand {
  100% { flex: 1 0 200px; }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
</main>
```